# Query conversion into hibernate annotation query form

Tags: hibernate

```
select ps.* from ucs

inner join ucs_service_definition usd

on USD.CONTROL_SYSTEM_TKEY = UCS.CONTROL_SYSTEM_TKEY

inner join programming_stream ps

on PS.PROGRAMMING_STREAM_TKEY = USD.PROGRAMMING_STREAM_TKEY
```

I need help to write above query into hibernate equivalent form.
Could u please give me suggestion.

Comment: hibernate equivalent you mean JPQL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select e from ucs e inner join e.CONTROL_SYSTEM_TKEY d join d.PROGRAMMING_STREAM_TKEY
```

To make this works you should have mapped the relationships, the above is JPQL and hibernate can handle .
Or try criteria queries

```
Root<Ucs> fromUpdates = query.from(Ucs.class);
Join<Ucs, Usd> details = fromUpdates.join("CONTROL_SYSTEM_TKEY ");
Join<Usd, ProgrammingStream> ps = details.join("PROGRAMMING_STREAM_TKEY");
```

Assuming the names of the entities.